# How to restore nuget packages by CLI and preserve directory packages?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, restore, nuget-package-restore

I have a major project  with more 3 projects

[Directory Visual Studio project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYVSY.png)

both have NuGet packages as a dependency, but when executing the command

```
nuget restore TestesGerais.sln
```

it creates a "packages" folder in root with all the packages of the 3 projects

[Folder package create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5olG.png)

And when trying to Build it, it gives a **reference error** because its references are pointing to the internal folder of Projects 1, 2 and 3

[Reference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgcgc.png)

Is there any way to create a "packages" folder in each project?

I read the documentation of the CLI of NuGet, I came to research ways to get a list with dependencies of nuget by the CLI as well and I was not successful in my research and practices.

Comment: Welcome on SO  having only one `packages` folder is by design and cannot be changed. To better understand the reference error, it would help if you could add the `sln`, `csproj`, and `packages.config` files. Or even better, create a GitHub sample project

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I adopted the bad practice of uploading the packages folder to the repository but in my context it was the only way to solve this.